# PHP header('Location ... after include not working

Tags: php, redirect, include

I try to redirect someone after a login. I actually did this a lot and now i'm facing a strange problem.

I have created a very short testfile to show the problem:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'db.php';
include 'sessionhelpers.inc.php';


header('Location: ../login.php?e=x');
exit();
?>
```

When i don't include db.php it works. When i include it, it doesn't. The strange thing is - i even delted the whole content of the file db.php and it still doesnt work. Also the file itself is workign because I use it at many other points in my code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any error ? Do you have an empty line before the first php open tag (<?php) in the db.php file ?

Comment: turn on error_reporting

Comment: can you tell me how to turn on error reporting?

Comment: Your `db.php` makes some output, breaking the order of the http response.

Comment: It actually says Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/www/users/greysc/php/db.php:1) in /usr/www/users/greysc/php/test.php on line 8 I do not have any output before this - just as seen in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only scenario i can think of is that you have a BOM character in one of your files.
You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
Open your files with your ftp client. Check at the top if there is a strange character in any of these files and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a die(); before your "header('Location...')" statement, and check your html page source code.
You may have a non blank output... preventing your http redirection to work.

Answer (score 0):

I bet db.php has white space before the first php tag. Delete the white space and you're fine.

Comment: No it doesnt... it's not like it wouldn't work in all the other includes

Comment: You could try changing the file encoding and line endings. That could be it.

Comment: <?php
 $user = "greysc_1"; ... - it's fixed now. It was a BOM character at the beginning